# how i can get mailjet required_once email.php file to send email in plain/core php

Tags: php, email, smtp, mailjet

I found an email sending example php code from mailjet site https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php, so I'm trying to send email but not load library in plain php code. In below example, I don't know how I can get `required_once("email.php")`.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue? Is there any possibility to send email using mailjet smtp in core php.

**example code**

```
<?php
    require_once "email.php";
    $headers = array ('From' => 'You <myemail@gmail.com>','Subject' => 'My first email by Mailjet');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I'm using phpMailer library to achieve this goal to send bulk of emails.